# Is data denormalizing still necessary for Cassandra if I use it with ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, denormalization

So far all the articles I read about Cassandra all mentions about doing data denormalizing/duplication to improve read performance (e.g. [ebay blog](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/ and [cassandra blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)). But to me it seems like the use case is only if you are using Cassandra as the main database for querying.

Currently I have ElasticSearch indexed my Cassandra DB (where everything is still normalized), so does it make sense for me to still denormalize my Cassandra DB given that *all* my queries actually go through ElasticSearch (ie. it will return list of ids and I fetch the ids directly from Cassandra)?